# Fill NA by rows after find a criteria based on columns

Tags: r

I am trying to solve a little dilem with a data frame in `R`. I have the next data frame `DF` with this structure(I add `dput()` version in the final part):

```
Key M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7
001  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  1
002 NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA
003 NA NA NA  1  1 NA  1
004 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1
005 NA NA NA  1 NA NA  1
006  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
007 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1
```

This data frame has and ID column (`Key`) and several columns with `NA` and `1`. I want to fill each row that contains `NA` in the next pattern: When there are two `NA` and a previous `1` and a last `1` after the two `NA`, then both `NA` have to be filled with `1`. If the pattern is not found, the elements in the rows must keep their original form. For example, in the first row there are two patterns: `1 NA NA 1` and `1 NA NA 1`, then `NA` must be filled with `1`. I would like to get a result like this:

```
Key M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7
001  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
002 NA NA  1  1  1  1 NA
003 NA NA NA  1  1 NA  1
004 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1
005 NA NA NA  1  1  1  1
006  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
007 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1
```

Where the patterns have been filled with `1`. I have tried using `na.locf()` from `zoo` package, but it changes the rest of `NAs` in `DF`. The `dput()` version of `DF` is the next:

```
structure(list(Key = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", 
"007"), M1 = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), M2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), M3 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1), M4 = c(1, NA, 
1, NA, 1, NA, NA), M5 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), M6 = c(NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), M7 = c(1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1)), .Names = c("Key", 
"M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Sorry @akrun, I have edited my data. Due to format they were changed to `character`. Thanks

Comment: very interesting and tricky problem, certainly a lot of different answers possibles!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use run length encoding to find two NAs in a row, for each row:

```
i <- t(apply(is.na(df[-1]), 1, function(x){
    r <- rle(x)

    # 2 NAs in a row => lengths = 2 & value is is.na true 
    r$values = r$lengths == 2 & r$values 

    # don't modify first / last run of the series
    r$values[1] <- r$values[length(r$lengths)] <- FALSE 

    inverse.rle(r)
}))

df[-1][i] <- 1
df


#   Key M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7
# 1 001  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
# 2 002 NA NA  1  1  1  1 NA
# 3 003 NA NA NA  1  1 NA  1
# 4 004 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1
# 5 005 NA NA NA  1  1  1  1
# 6 006  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 7 007 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1
```

This way, you don't need to convert to a character and back.

Comment: I was thinking about a way with rle but finally opted for regex. Your solution is very nice , +1

Answer (score 2):

```
mat <- as.matrix(df[-1])
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0L
strings <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse=""))
pattern_matches <- str_locate_all(strings, "(?=(1001))")
strloc <- sapply(pattern_matches, function(x) c(x[,"start"]))
for(i in seq(nrow(mat))) mat[i,strloc[[i]]+rep(1:2,each=length(strloc[[i]]))] <- 1
is.na(mat) <- mat==0
as.data.frame(cbind(df[1],mat))
#   Key M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7
# 1 001  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
# 2 002 NA NA  1  1  1  1 NA
# 3 003 NA NA NA  1  1 NA  1
# 4 004 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1
# 5 005 NA NA NA  1  1  1  1
# 6 006  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 7 007 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1
```

I took a similar approach as @ColonelBeauvel, but used the matrix structure instead. First assign `0` to all NA values. Then paste each row together. Match the pattern "1001" with `str_locate_all` from the `stringr` package. For anyone wondering, the advantage of the full pattern `"(?=(1001))"`, is that it allows a portion of one match to be used in the next match, called a "non-consuming regular expression".

We then locate the start of each match and assign '1' to the two zeroes adjacent to it.

Comment: Really useful new trick for me that non consuming regular expression.

Comment: Very useful. great explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups

Comment: I'd definitely have used a second pattern matching attempt if there was a pattern match the first time, in order to capture 1s that belong to two consecutive matches. Two times is enough as the column number is 7 and the pattern length is 4. But with this trick no need for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which does the job, surely can be improved without converting `NA` to `0` and use gsub with lookaround (but I am not a regex killer!).

`m` is your original `data.frame`:

```
x = do.call(paste, c(data.frame(1*!is.na(m[-1])), sep=''))

y = gregexpr('(?=1001)', x, perl=T)

func = function(u,v)
{
    if(any(u!=-1))
        sapply(u, function(i) substr(v, start=i, stop=i+2) <<- '111')

    as.numeric(strsplit(v,'')[[1]])
}

df = cbind(list('key'=m[,1]), data.frame(do.call(rbind, Map(func, y, x))))
df[df==0] = NA

#  key X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
#1 001  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#2 002 NA NA  1  1  1  1 NA
#3 003 NA NA NA  1  1 NA  1
#4 004 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1
#5 005 NA NA NA  1  1  1  1
#6 006  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
#7 007 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1
```